# Java project as server side and phonegap as client side

Tags: java, cordova, client-server

I'm new to phonegap, and i've created a new phonegap application that need to communicate with my server. 
The server is a java application project (netbeans), that listen to connections.

I'm trying to connect my phonegap app to the server, but without any luck.. 
I thought to use servlet to get an http requests..

any ideas?

Comment: communicate using AJAX (jQuery for example) through some REST API on your java server.

Comment: so there is no need to servlet? can i use soap instead rest?

Comment: yes. yes. I think REST would be easier though. you can check RESTeasy or Jersey for rest solutions.

Comment: @MarcinMikołajczyk so it will still deal with a multiple users? 
My own server is a java application that runs in my pc and i implemented it to deal with multiple users, what i want to do is when a user connect from the phonegap is to store his credentials and next time when he is logging in to set a socket (session) between the server and him